# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Network is unreachable whilst laravel hosting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, hosting, laravel-5.3

I have hosted two websites and now uploaded third one but it says

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Network is unreachable
```

What is wrong? Why is this shown?

Credentials are right!

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.0
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=vfcvfmim_databaseorganiser
DB_USERNAME=vfcvfmim_abc
DB_PASSWORD=abc
```

Comment: Your database settings are probably incorrect. Is your DB host correct for your new website?

Comment: Yesss. I added subdomain and then uploaded this website.

Comment: Contact your host to find out why you can't use your settings to connect to the database.

Comment: Show me your `.env` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahan! I see `127.0.0.0` could be the problem. Try with `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` .

Check if it works.

Comment: Sure, my pleasure